# Show input on second screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I would like to show the textfield input from screen `Eingabe` in the label from the second screen `Ausgabe`. I do not understand the reference from the kivy language.
Thanks!
I always get an error:

```
self or 'ausgabe' is not defined
```

How can I access the value from the textfield input from the first screen in the second screen class `Ausgabe` and display the result in the label von the second screen?

main.py:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from time import sleep
from kivy.metrics import dp

class Eingabe(MDScreen):
    kapital = ObjectProperty(None)
    text1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    t = ''
    def btn(self):
        print(self.kapital.text)
        self.text1.text = str('Endsumme: ' + self.kapital.text)
    
        t = self.kapital.text
    pass


class Ausgabe(MDScreen):
     #tabelle = ObjectProperty(None)
    eingabe1 = ausgabe.manager.get_screen('eingabe')
    self.ausgabe.text = str(eingabe1.t)
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

Window.size = (540, 960)

class main2App(MDApp):
    title = "Sparplanrechner"

    def build(self):
        #self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue" 
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        return Builder.load_file("main2.kv")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main2App().run()
```

main2.kv:

```
WindowManager:
    Eingabe:
    Ausgabe:

<Eingabe>:
    name: "eingabe"
    
    kapital: kapital
    rate: rate
    zins: zins
    zeit: zeit
    text1: text1
    ausgabe: ausgabe
    
    MDGridLayout:
        #adaptive_size: True
        md_bg_color: 1,1,1,1
        padding: dp(40)
        spacing: dp(40)
        cols: 1
        
            
      
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Steuerfreibetrag"
            id: zeit
            font_size: sp(20)
            helper_text: "Steuerfreibetrag (i.d.R. 801€)"
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            mode: "rectangle"
            fill_color: 0, 0, 0, 0            
        
        MDLabel:
            text: ''
            id: text1
            halign: "center"
            valign: 'middle'
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 207,95,54, 1
            font_style: "H6"
            bold: True
            
        MDGridLayout:
            #adaptive_size: True
            md_bg_color: 1,1,1,1
            padding: dp(40)
            spacing: dp(40)
            cols: 2
            
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "Berechnen"
                #text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                font_size: "20sp"
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':.5}
                on_release: root.btn()        
                
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "Zeige Deteils"
                font_size: "20sp"
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':.5}
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "ausgabe"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

<Ausgabe>:
    name: "ausgabe"
    #tabelle: tabelle
    
    #MDDataTable:
     #   id: tabelle
        #column_data:[("Column 1", dp(30)),("Column 4", dp(30))]
    MDLabel:
            text: ''
            id: ausgabe
            halign: "center"
            valign: 'middle'
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 207,95,54, 1
            font_style: "H6"
            bold: True

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Go Back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "eingabe"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the `on_enter()` method of the `Ausgabe` `Screen`, like this:

```
class Ausgabe(MDScreen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.ausgabe.text = self.manager.get_screen('eingabe').zeit.text
```

The `on_enter()` method is called when the screen is displayed, so it will update the `MDLabel` whenever the `Ausgabe` `Screen` is shown.

Comment: Thank you very much!